# React front from Spring back with security. Security doesn't allow to see home page

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am making my first app with react and Spring security. I tried to learn with examples and tutorials online, namely he example from https://dzone.com/articles/integrating-spring-boot-and-react-with-spring-secu-1 into a WAR package (my requirement). It all works without security but when I add security my home page is blank and the console says 401 to every request. I want to show the login page which is not secured. I tried to use addResourceHandlers but it makes the matters only worse and shows 404. This config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/")
        .addResourceLocations("frontend/build/static/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/** .js")
        .addResourceLocations("frontend/build/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/** .json")
        .addResourceLocations("frontend/build/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/** .ico")
        .addResourceLocations("frontend/build/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html")
        .addResourceLocations("frontend/build/index.html");
    }
```

My web security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class JWTWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;

    @Value("${jwt.get.token.uri}")
    private String authenticationPath;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderBean());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

       httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  //H2 Console Needs this setting
            .cacheControl(); //disable caching
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.POST,
                authenticationPath
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                "/" //Other Stuff You want to Ignore
            )
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**");//Should not be in Production!
    }
}
```

My properties:

```
jwt.signing.key.secret=mySecret
jwt.get.token.uri=/authenticate
jwt.refresh.token.uri=/refresh
jwt.http.request.header=Authorization
jwt.token.expiration.in.seconds=604800
server.servlet.context-path=/Spring-Boot-React
```

my App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <InstructorApp />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and my InstructorApp:

```
class InstructorApp extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Router basename="/Spring-Boot-React">
                    <>
                        <MenuComponent />
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact component={LoginComponent} />
                            <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginComponent} />
                            <AuthenticatedRoute path="/logout" exact component={LogoutComponent} />
                            <AuthenticatedRoute path="/courses" exact component={ListCoursesComponent} />
                        </Switch>
                    </>
                </Router>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default InstructorApp
```

with my main app which i based on this it's the same outcome but i first want to try to deploy this one from tutorials. The package names are different because I used another tutoruial where the war built correctly(the original has too different a pom).
My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.frugalis</groupId>
   <artifactId>Spring-Boot-React</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>Spring-Boot-React</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath />
      <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
   <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                 <warSourceExcludes>
                     WEB-INF/view/react/node/**,
                     WEB-INF/view/react/node_modules/**,
                     WEB-INF/view/react/public/**,
                     WEB-INF/view/react/src/**,
                     WEB-INF/view/react/*
                 </warSourceExcludes>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <workingDirectory>frontend/</workingDirectory>
               <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>install node and npm</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <nodeVersion>v12.14.0</nodeVersion>
                     <npmVersion>6.13.4</npmVersion>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>npm install</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>npm</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <arguments>install</arguments>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>npm run build</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>npm</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <arguments>run build</arguments>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                  <configuration>
                     <target>
                        <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/static">
                           <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/frontend/build" />
                        </copy>
                     </target>
                  </configuration>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Controlers and mappings from the back end:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins={ "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4200" })
public class JwtAuthenticationRestController {

  @Value("${jwt.http.request.header}")
  private String tokenHeader;

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Autowired
  private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "${jwt.get.token.uri}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtTokenRequest authenticationRequest)
      throws AuthenticationException {

    authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

    final UserDetails userDetails = jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtTokenResponse(token));
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "${jwt.refresh.token.uri}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<?> refreshAndGetAuthenticationToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authToken = request.getHeader(tokenHeader);
    final String token = authToken.substring(7);
    String username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(token);
    JwtUserDetails user = (JwtUserDetails) jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

    if (jwtTokenUtil.canTokenBeRefreshed(token)) {
      String refreshedToken = jwtTokenUtil.refreshToken(token);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtTokenResponse(refreshedToken));
    } else {
      return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
    }
  }

  @ExceptionHandler({ AuthenticationException.class })
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleAuthenticationException(AuthenticationException e) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(e.getMessage());
  }

  private void authenticate(String username, String password) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(username);
    Objects.requireNonNull(password);

    try {
      authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
    } catch (DisabledException e) {
      throw new AuthenticationException("USER_DISABLED", e);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
      throw new AuthenticationException("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4200" })
@RestController
public class CourseResource {

    @Autowired
    private CoursesHardcodedService courseManagementService;

    @GetMapping("/instructors/{username}/courses")
    public List<Course> getAllCourses(@PathVariable String username) {
        return courseManagementService.findAll();
    }
}
```

My structure looks like this:
[image: The frontend is in folder frontend]

Comment: did you create controller for the routings ?

Comment: This is a tutorial example (my real app is similar in structure but another topic and a bit bigger) and yes, there are mappings. in frontend they are in instructorapp which i posted above, i'll now add the rest api in edit